# How can I use same JS function using multiple classes of same name?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have this logic work for multiple elements of the same class. I have a list of navigation elements that are grouped into categories. I am using the same class multiple times, however the Javascript logic I've implemented only works for the first one.

How can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list_content all">
<div>
  <a class="ozone" href="#" data-image="https://thepropertyagency.com.au/upload/projects/ozone-s1.jpg">
    <li>Ozone Residences</li>
  </a>
</div> 
<div class="ozone_caption">
  <div class="caption_grid">
    <h1>Cronella NSW<br>Residential</h1>
    <h1><br>2018</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>

<ul class="list_content residential">
<div>
  <a class="ozone" href="#" data-image="https://thepropertyagency.com.au/upload/projects/ozone-s1.jpg">
    <li>Ozone Residences</li>
  </a>
</div> 
<div class="ozone_caption">
  <div class="caption_grid">
    <h1>Cronella NSW<br>Residential</h1>
    <h1><br>2018</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".ozone").mouseenter(function() {
  if ($(this).parent('div').children('div.image').length) {
    $(this).parent('div').children('div.image').show();
  } else {
    var image_name=$(this).data('image');
    var imageTag='<div class="image" style="position:absolute; right: 50px; bottom: 50px">'+'<img src="'+image_name+'" alt="image" height="500" />'+'</div>';
    $(this).parent('div').append(imageTag);
  }
});

$(".ozone").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').children('div.image').hide();
});

$('.ozone').hover(
  function() {
    $('.ozone_caption').css('opacity', '1')
  }, 
  function() { 
    $('.ozone_caption').css('opacity', '0')
  });
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant markup (HTML) of your page.

Comment: _"I am trying to have this function work..."_  which function?

Comment: Tell us what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: When you hover on each class it displays a particular image and caption, however, it only works on the first class in the markup and not any of the others after that of the same class name

Comment: Only seeing one class attribute in your markup.

Comment: in your code we don't see you using class at all only id's. edit your question and add code with class that you have tried.

Comment: Ahh sorry my bad, I was originally using id's but didn't update this one. Ok this should make things a bit clearer I hope

Comment: because you do not select the element that is related to it. You select all of the elements.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.each()` function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all the instances of the `ozone` class.

Note that you also have to alter the approach towards modifying the `ozone_caption` instances. I'm assuming you want to only operate on the associated `ozone_caption` instead of all of them.

```
$('.ozone').each(function() { 
  $(this).mouseenter(function() {
      if ($(this).parent('div').children('div.image').length) {
          $(this).parent('div').children('div.image').show();
      } else {
          var image_name=$(this).data('image');
          var imageTag='<div class="image" style="position:absolute; right: 50px; bottom: 50px">'+'<img src="'+image_name+'" alt="image" height="500" />'+'</div>';
          $(this).parent('div').append(imageTag);
      }
  });

  $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).parent('div').children('div.image').hide();
  });

  $(this).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).parent('div').next('.ozone_caption').css('opacity', '1')
    }, 
    function() { 
      $(this).parent('div').next('.ozone_caption').css('opacity', '0')
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Gonna post this answer for you, but I still don't know what you are trying to do exactly. Based on what you provided this should work but you'll have to customize it for your needs. Keep in mind with the absolute positioning, if you don't specify `position: relative;` on the parent it will use the `body`.

```js
$(".ozone").mouseenter(function()
  {
  var image = $(this).siblings('div.image');
  if (image.length) 
  {
    image.show();
    }
  else
    {
    var image_name=$(this).data('image');
    var imageTag='<div class="image">'+'<img src="'+image_name+'" alt="image" height="500" style="position:absolute; right: 50px; bottom: 50px" />'+'</div>';
    $(this).parent('div').append(imageTag);
    }
  });

$(".ozone").mouseleave(function()
  {
  $(this).siblings('div.image').hide();
});

$('.ozone').hover(function() 
  {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.ozone_caption').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list_content all">
<div>
  <a class="ozone" href="#" data-image="https://thepropertyagency.com.au/upload/projects/ozone-s1.jpg">
    <li>Ozone Residences</li>
  </a>
</div> 
<div class="ozone_caption">
  <div class="caption_grid">
    <h1>Cronella NSW<br>Residential</h1>
    <h1><br>2018</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>

<ul class="list_content residential">
<div>
  <a class="ozone" href="#" data-image="https://thepropertyagency.com.au/upload/projects/ozone-s1.jpg">
    <li>Ozone Residences</li>
  </a>
</div> 
<div class="ozone_caption">
  <div class="caption_grid">
    <h1>Cronella NSW<br>Residential</h1>
    <h1><br>2018</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
```